# SSO with multiple domains. How to create Community Sessions for one portal user in salesforce?

Tags: single-sign-on, community, session, mydomain

There is multiple domains for the communities in the org. User have to be able to have an opportunity to log in into all communities via one.

Example : Communities A,B. From external site_X User_1 logs into A. Then he goes to external site_Y, from Y he wants to see protected information and now its requires Login into community B.

Is it possible to create Community Sessions for multiple domains for one portal user in Salesforce ?
Are there any ways to make this scenario work?

P.S. Example works with one domain in sandbox.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Related question: is it possible to login into different communities from one controller? Is it possible to use Site.login() for this or there are different ways to do this?